# javascript function bg color

Tags: javascript, html

I made a button with a function to change background color to red but I get an error saying function1 is not defined.

HTML code:

```
<button onclick="function1()">Change bg color to black</button>
```

JavaScript code in external JS file named main.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>
```

containing

```
function function1 () {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: Show your whole code

Comment: What is your `HTML` structure. The main reason for such errors is the `script` not being loaded yet due to which the function is not found.

Comment: try adding `type="button"` to the button so it does not submit the page in some browsers

Comment: `scr = "main.js">` typo? Should be `src = "main.js"`

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your code. You wrote:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" scr = "main.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>
```

It's `src`, not `scr`.

Answer (score 0):

bu246:

Probably you didn't declare your function in the right section:

**bgcolor.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="main.js"></script>

<body>

<button onclick="function1()">Change bg color to black</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**main.js:**

```
function function1 () {
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: Im using external .js   <script type="text/javascript" scr = "main.js"></script>

Comment: The function is called after a full load of DOM and scripts. I don't think the issue relies in order.

Comment: And what is the difference?

Comment: The problem was the background image in style.css. When I removed it the button was working fine.

Comment: bu246, you can set the property "!important" to your css code, in order to force the browser to accept the new value, instead of the one in the file  style.css: background-color: #E5D403 !important;